# How do I turn off 301 redirecting posts (not canonical)?

Tags: permalinks, redirect, htaccess, seo

I noticed a strange behavior in WordPress where it automatically 301 redirects certain URL structures for posts.

For example, I have a post entry for:
mysite.com/999/about-us

Then, you would think the following link would produce a 404:
mysite.com/567891/about-us-1

However, WordPress automatically redirects to /999/about-us

Is there a way to turn off this specific kind of redirect? It seems like WP is looking for the closest "like" slug.  Note that I have no entries for about-us-1 in the posts table, and no revisions or anything that would cause WP to forward like this.

I found this snippit that turns off canonical 301 redirects:

```
remove_filter('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');
```

However, this isn't the solution because it produces undesired URL structures on the site.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to have to do with `redirect_guess_404_permalink()` called on line 96 of `wp-includes/canonical.php`. Just to test, I added a `return false;` to the first line of the `redirect_guess_404_permalink()` function, and that seemed to stop this odd behavior. I'm poking around a bit, but so far I don't see a **good** way to fix this without editing that core WordPress file (which I am personally opposed to doing in a production environment, since it makes core updates more difficult and accident prone). I wish there was a good filter/action hook to use in `redirect_guess_404_permalink` to shortcut this behavior. I'll keep poking a bit and update this answer if I find a good solution.

**EDIT**

I may have found a fix, which I tested briefly and worked.

***Edit (again)*** Added some logic (which replicates the checks done in [canonical.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/canonical.php) to perform the redirect) to check for certain query parameters. Not as well tested as the last edit, so let me know how it works. If not 100% working, it should at least get you in the right direction (and check [canonical.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/canonical.php)).

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'remove_404_redirect', 1);
function remove_404_redirect(){
  if (is_404()){
    $id = max(get_query_var('p'), get_query_var('page_id'), get_query_var('attachment_id'));
    $redirect_url = false;
    if ($id && $redirect_post = get_post($id)) {
      $post_type_obj = get_post_type_object($redirect_post->post_type);
      if ($post_type_obj->public)
        $redirect_url = get_permalink($redirect_post);
    }
    if (!$redirect_url)
      remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
  }
}
```

This will work because the undesired redirects are only occurring if the page is initially a 404, so we just check for 404 and, if it is, remove the redirecting filter. YAY!

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for finding that - I dug for a while but wasn't able to find it.  An elegant solution sounds spectacular.

Comment: Hey @AlexCook , check my edit of the answer. I think that should work to fix this issue.

Comment: Looks like using this broke ?p=xxx forwarding, which is potentially a big issue. When I added this hack, it prevented those types of forwards from working.

Comment: @AlexCook Good catch, I updated my answer again. While not as elegant, it should resolve this issue. It replicates more exactly the checks done in `canonical.php` in the `is_404()` check around line 83. Hope that fixes it for good :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler take. Only turn off the redirecting if none of the query_vars are present. In this way we get to keep the functionality, without the need to duplicate the logic already at redirect_canonical.

```
add_filter('redirect_canonical', 'no_redirect_on_404', 10, 2);
function no_redirect_on_404($redirect_url, $requested_url){
    $id = max(get_query_var('p'), get_query_var('page_id'), get_query_var('attachment_id'), 
            get_query_var('day'), get_query_var('monthnum'), get_query_var('year'));
    if (is_404() && !$id){
        return false;
    }
    return $redirect_url;
}
```