# Can each user have only access to a private area (his own categories and posts)?

Tags: categories

I am working on a wordpress site and one of the key features i want to have is the fact that each user, once registered should be able to :

- create his own categories (that will be visible only by him)
- create posts in his own categories
- access only to the content he created (cotegories/posts)

So his front end view should be only his posts and the categories he created.

Is there a way for achieving this with Wordpress? I made a lot of search on the net, but i didn't find any answer for this specific question.

EDIT : The main idea of my question is : is there a way to separate data per user (not only their login, passwd and profile) that would include the categories that each user would create and the posts in these categories? Each user will have in this case a unique vue (his own directory) on the site with only his categories & posts.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to build a [custom plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72183/12615) with bits and pieces [found researching](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Buser+%2Bcategories) this Stack. But maybe this is a case for an already existent plugin: [Role Scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/), not an easy one, but may accomplish the task.

Comment: Thanks brasofilo, i had a look at Role Scoper and i think it can be used to setup restrictions on each new registered user. But it is not solving the point for the own categories per user. Does anyone knows how to use custom Post Types or Taxonomies for this purpose ? Thx

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the use cases to use WordPress in [network configuration](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network). In this configuration a user has a unique control over his content.

Answer (score 0):

1- user can only access to they´re own posts? - can be archive (plus editor rol, and admin can edit as well).

2- user can only access to they´re own categories? - i believe categories are shared by all users and they must be pre field by some editor or administrator.

3 - you can use instance Tag´s, or some other "custom field" to allow users managing a sort of categories you/they need.

Comment: Thanks Jose for your answer. More help would be very appreciated on this if someone has more precise ideas / implementation examples.

Comment: i think you will have always the categories issue. But hell, im sure if you get into deeply you can do it. Although the same results can be achieve in a different perspective that´s why i was proposing the "tag´s" or "new custom field" for that categories purpose.