# How to show a under construction page for a domain but still be able to work on index.php?

Tags: templates

I installed a WordPress for a domain name. When I use this domain name will point to `index.php` in my template. I want show a under construction page for this domain name, but the other hand I still want work on `index.php` in my template.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can filter `template_include` and include a special file for users who are not logged in:

```
/* Plugin Name: T5 Under Construction */

add_filter( 'template_include', 't5_uc_template' );

function t5_uc_template( $template )
{
    $uc_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/under-construction.php';

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        return $uc_template;

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) )
        return $uc_template;

    return $template;
}
```

The file `under-construction.php` could be a plain HTML file; it doesn’t have to be a PHP file.

Comment: I'm sorry for this but.. What file I need to put that code?

Comment: @SoldierCorp [Make a plugin with this code](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/where-do-i-put-the-code-snippets-i-found-here-or-somewhere-else-on-the-web).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest workaround would be to just add the static content in a new `index.html` file in the root, and the server should read the `.html` before the `.php`

Comment: That would affect all users, including the administrator.

Comment: But then you'd only change the _Index_, not the overall access to the website. Any _deep link_ (such as `http://example.com/category/post-name/` etc.) still would work.

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict depending on the IP address and Htaccess file.

```
<Files index.php>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 12.34.56.78
</Files>
```

where 12.34.56.78 is your ip address.

Answer (score 1):

Use maintenance mode plugin. Activate it. Once activate login as admin and you can only view your site. Other users can see maintenance message.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be using an maintenance or coming soon plugin. It will take a minute or 2 to setup the plugin and you're good to go.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-maintenance-mode/

Answer (score 0):

You can just hook the **[current_user_can()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/)** function and the **[is_user_logged_in()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/)** function to **[get_header](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/)** like this:

```
function shillongtitude_construction_mode() {
    if (!current_user_can(‘edit_themes’) || !is_user_logged_in()) {
      wp_die('<h1>Construction going on.</h1><br />Site currently under construction.');
    }
}
add_action('get_header', 'shillongtitude_construction_mode');
```