# Set default text for the editor in new posts

Tags: editor, customization

I was wondering, is it possible to set default text to appear inside "text" part of the wysiwyg located on Create post page? So every time you click add new post that text would be there waiting for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a filter named `default_content`. It does exactly what the name says. :)

Example:

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 't5_preset_editor_content', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Fills the default content for post type 'post' if it is not empty.
 *
 * @param string $content
 * @param object $post
 * @return string
 */
function t5_preset_editor_content( $content, $post )
{
    if ( '' !== $content or 'post' !== $post->post_type )
    {
        return $content;
    }

    return 'This is the <em>default</em> content. You may customize it.';
}
```

As you can see, the post type is already available, so you could set different defaults for different post types.

Related filters are `default_title` and `default_excerpt`. They work the same way.

You can also send someone a link with parameters for `content`, `post_title` and `excerpt`:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?content=hello+world%21&post_title=Sample+Title&excerpt=custom+excerpt
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I type too slowly, apparently.  Exactly the answer I was going to give.

Comment: @PatJ I didn’t type [that much](https://gist.github.com/toscho/2405345).

Comment: toscho has beaten me before too @PatJ :)

Comment: @toscho goes into functions.php correct?

Comment: @IlyaKnaup [Please, no.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php) :) Make a plugin for that, something like [this one](https://gist.github.com/toscho/2405345).

Comment: @IlyaKnaup Also see: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/where-do-i-put-the-code-snippets-i-found-here-or-somewhere-else-on-the-web