# Custom post type data not displaying If I select the category from the dropdonw

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, get-posts

I have created a custom post type. I am able to add all the details and it's working.
I have a dropdown and I am getting my category in that dropdown. Once the user selects the category from the dropdown then data will display accoringly.

I tried the below code but I am not getting anything. Even error is also not showing.

```
function eventsView( $atts ){
    if($atts['cat']=='All'){            
        $upcomingevents = get_posts(array(
          'showposts' => 80, //add -1 if you want to show all posts
          'post_type' => 'events'
          ));
    }else{  
        $upcomingevents = get_posts(array(
          'showposts' => 10, //add -1 if you want to show all posts
          'post_type' => 'events',
          'tax_query' => array(
              array(
            'taxonomy' => 'events_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $atts['cat'] //pass your term name here
              )
            ))
           );
    }   
    echo"<pre>";
    print_r($upcomingevents); // Nothing is showing int his variable.

  // some more code here like foreach conditon
}
```

Comment: We would need to know what you're providing through your $atts. Did you test by putting in one of your actual slugs instead of referencing $atts['cat']?  I also believe you should be calling 'numberposts' or 'posts_per_page' and not 'showposts'.  Lastly, why did you choose get_posts instead of a wp_query?

Answer (score 0):

did you try a solution like this [Include custom post type in "all posts"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98213/include-custom-post-type-in-all-posts/98214#98214) - Custom Post Types must be included in the main_query first - to be available in the loop output.

Comment: I have 2-3 more custom posts on my website and that is working.  I don't know why I am not getting the output in this post.