# Editing Category RSS Feeds

Tags: php, rss, feed

I have the following PHP code below that I would like to add to the category feed in WordPress.

```
<?php if(get_the_post_thumbnail()): ?>
<featured-item><?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?></featured-item>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I know that I can edit `feed-rss2.php` to add it into the general feed. But the same code isn't allowing me to add it to the category view of the same RSS feed.

Where do I place this code for the generated RSS feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, you should *never* hack the WordPress core files. Instead, WordPress provides the handy `rss2_item` action hook. All we need to do is check if we're on a category feed or not:

```
function wpse_99336_category_feed_item() {

    if ( is_category() && get_the_post_thumbnail() ) {
        printf ( '<featured-item>%s</featured-item>',
            wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() )
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'rss2_item', 'wpse_99336_category_feed_item' );
```

Comment: Right I can see that but I'm not sure WHERE to add this in so it gets the hook. If I edit the core files with that edit above, specifically "add_action", I get an error on the feed page.

Comment: @PaulWilliams See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/where-do-i-put-the-code-snippets-i-found-here-or-somewhere-else-on-the-web

Comment: Okay so I do this as a plugin, that's all?

Comment: Yep. Or use another method mentioned in the above link