# wp enqueue style and style sheet depth

Tags: php, css

How could I add a style sheet at the bottom of the `<head>` tag, so if there´s a need to override some other styles added before, it will override.

I heard something about wp_enqueue_style, and it seems there´s a depth parameter. 
Is that what I need? To make my style sheet be the last one at the `<head>` tag?

If yes, what should I put in the parameter `depth`?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the [Codex page for `wp_enqueue_style()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style). As @toscho mentions in his answer below, you can tell WordPress that your stylesheet *depends* on others, and have it after them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a priority number to the wp_enqueue_scripts action. So you could could give the action hooked to the enqueue of yourstyle sheet a priority of 999. Like so:

```
function high_priority_style() {
  Wp_enqueue_style('important', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/important.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'high_priority_style', '999');
```

A simpler way to do is enqueue all of your stylesheets, including style.css in the same function, hooked to wp_enqueue_scripts and they will be added in the order that they appear in the function, like this:

```
  function styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style('low-priority', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/low-priority.css');
  wp_enqueue_style('theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
  wp_enqueue_style('important', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/important.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'styles');
```

I included a lower priority stylesheet in this example, that would be something like the CSS for a framework or grid system.

Make sure to remove any hard coded links to any stylesheets in header.php when adding styles this way (ie the right way.)

Comment: Should I put, the last code, on `functions.php` or in `header.php`?

Comment: Is it a plugin?

Comment: @MarceloNoronha in functions.php

Answer (score 3):

From the source, reformatted for better readability:

```
function wp_enqueue_style( 
    $handle, // unique name 
    $src = false, // URL
    $deps = array(), // array of dependencies, other styleheets unique names.
    $ver = false, // version
    $media = 'all' // media
)
```

So, `$deps` is an array of unique stylesheet handles. If you list the stylesheets here you want to wait for, WordPress will create the proper order automatically for you.

Example:

```
$template_dir_uri = get_template_directory_uri();
wp_register_style( 'style_1', "$template_dir_uri/style1.css" );
wp_register_style( 'style_2', "$template_dir_uri/style2.css" );
wp_register_style( 'style_3', "$template_dir_uri/style3.css", array ( 'style_1', 'style_2' )  );
wp_register_style( 'style_4', "$template_dir_uri/style4.css", array ( 'style_3', 'default_theme_css_handle' ) );

wp_enqueue_style( 'style_4' );
```

Now the `<link>` elements for the stylesheets will be printed in the correct order *1, 2, 3, 4*.

Comment: and name for other stylesheets must be handles not file names.

Comment: @TweetPressFr There is no mention of a file name.

Comment: I did not say that for your answer, it's just that this error is pretty common.

Comment: What would be the $handle // unique name of a style sheet with the file name "ie.css"?

Comment: @MarceloNoronha `$handle` can be any string, it is not related to file names.

Comment: Where should I put the example code? Which file which part?

Comment: [Where do I put the code snippets?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72183/73)

Comment: Put it in functions.php

Comment: OP, make sure, if you go this route, that you put this code in a function and hook that function to the wp_enqeue_scripts action.

Comment: how that would be?

Comment: Hi. I´ve made the code as a plugin and it this is what happened:

My "ie.css", is added last as I wanted, but, there´s the theme´s css that (I don´t know why), are added even below the    'ie.css'. The theme I´m using is "Snapshot" from "WooThemes".

Comment: I´ve added a high priority to 'ie.css' — 999. I placed this code into functions.php.

function high_priority_style() {
  wp_enqueue_style('style_5', get_template_directory_uri() . '/ie.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'high_priority_style', '999');

Comment: @MarceloNoronha Set the theme stylesheet handle as dependency for your stylesheets. See my update. This will fail if the theme doesn’t use `wp_enqueue_style()`.

Comment: How could I know the stylesheet handle of the theme?

Comment: Wait I think I found on theme-options

Comment: The styles sheets of the theme, don´t include an id that I could use as a handle.

See page source code:

http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/

Comment: And that´s the url of the theme-options.php:

http://www.mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/wp-content/themes/snapshot/includes/theme-options.php