# How to load css files in a specific order

Tags: plugins, css

I'm wondering if someone can help me with this. The theme I am working on has a custom theme options page where you can select various colors for the website. The problem is that the stylesheet it produces loads before the bootstrap and main stylesheet in header.php. I need this to load after those two. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Have you read about [stylesheet dependencies](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96161/how-to-enqueue-style-before-style-css) ([another explanation](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99468/73))?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I think it's because the various color stylesheets are being enqueued from my theme-options.php file instead of the functions.php file.

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution. I just added a number at the end like this..

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'moana_enqueue_color_scheme', 789 );

Comment: That'll work too, as that *number* is actually the priority in which the callbacks are rendered in an action hook. But, you'll need to create separate callbacks for each of your stylesheets and use priorities accordingly. The best way is using the stylesheet dependencies, which gives you much more control over the enqueued scripts and stylesheets.