# Display All Sticky Post Before Regular Post

Tags: posts, loop, sticky-post

I would like to display all of my sticky post and then regular post thereafter. I am new to WordPress and not sure how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
---------               
Sticky 1                
--------- 
---------               
Sticky 2               
---------  
---------               
Sticky 3...                
---------  
---------               
Normal 1                
---------
---------               
Normal 2....                
---------
```

Comment: Hi Suresh.  Do you mean you want to make every post sticky?  Do you mean you want to display 1 single sticky post whenever you display any other single post?

Comment: Hi Steve...I want to display sticky post first and another post...

Comment: hi steve.. just if i click another post then also.. first i want to display sticky post first then another post second

Comment: for example.. i have one sticky post.. i want to display this sticky post for each and every post ...

Comment: i want to post my sticky first and normal post... if i click any post.. the display must be like this.. first sticky post should be display then normal post..

Comment: @suresh a few things: 1) Calm yourself, Be Patient. We are all volunteers trying to help you. It can take hours/days sometimes for an answer. 2) You should/can edit your own question instead of commenting as that gets confusing. 3) Please wait a minute and I'll write an answer now that I understand the question.

Comment: not only for home page.. it should be for all posts pages also.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [custom loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to get all stick post and then return all normal post. You may have to modify this code a bit but here is how you can return all sticky post. You can play with the second custom loop for the individual pages and return just the one post.

```
//is sticky 
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
if(!empty($sticky)){
 $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1, //get all post
    'post__in'  => $sticky, //are they sticky post
 );

 // The Query
 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

 // The Loop //we are only getting a list of the title as a li see the loop docs for details on the loop or copy this from index.php (or posts.php)
 while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
 }
 wp_reset_query(); //reset the original WP_Query
}

//now get the not sticky post
$args2 = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1, //get all post
    'post__not_in'  => $sticky, //are they NOT sticky post
);
// The Query
$the_query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );

// The Loop....
```

This is a bit of starter code as I'm not going to write your project for you and it's hard to figure out exactly what you're trying to do without code/visual example.

Comment: where this code should i paste in my template

Comment: @suresh [Where do I put the code snippets?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72183/73)

Comment: @suresh paste it (especially the first loop) wherever you want to display all sticky post.

Comment: It's strange but the first part returns all posts when none is checked as sticky... When some sticky present, it behaves right...

Comment: I see the problem i mentioned above is caused by empty array in post__in parameter. Proposed edit to your code.