# How to put forward a blog post

Tags: custom-field, query-posts

I would know if I can put forward a blog post natively using Wordpress ?

For example, I have created 20 posts, but I only show 5 on my homepage.
Then imagine that I want to put the 18th at the first place ?
By default Wordpress order by publication date. I was thinking about creating a custom field called for example 'highlighting' with a boolean value and order by this new field, but it has its limit if there is more than one post to 'highlight'.

So my exact question is: There is a native way to this with Wordpress ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you heard about sticky posts?

Comment: Nope I'm totally new with wordpress

Comment: You can make a post sticky and it will stick at top, first in row for as long as you want. To make a post sticky, you will need to select sticky option. Read more about [sticky posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts) on Codex.

Comment: You tagged your question as `query-posts`, I should note that you should never use the `query_posts` function, it is there for compatibility/legacy reasons, use `WP_Query` or the `pre_get_posts` filter instead

Comment: Also @Roberthue you should add that as an answer

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell, just added. And KeizerBridge, as tom suggested, do not use `query-posts`, use `WP_Query` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [Sticky Posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts) feature in WordPress.

When you make a post sticky, it shows up above your new posts. As name suggests, that particular post will stick at top, first in the row for as long as you want.

> Sticky Posts is a feature introduced with Version 2.7. A check box is
>   included on the Administration > Posts > Add New Screen (In the
>   Publish panel under Visibility. Click edit to see the checkbox). If
>   checked, the post will be placed at the top of the front page of
>   posts, keeping it there until new posts are published. Please notice
>   that this feature is only available for the built-in post type post
>   and not for custom post types.

Comment: Thank you and thank you Tom for your advice, I didn't know. But On the documentation of the sticky post I can't see anything about Get the last stickypost but also the other post. EDIT: I found the solution: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104127/display-all-sticky-post-before-regular-post

Comment: Last sticky post? If you want any post to appear first on your posts list (regardless of post order and time), you can make it sticky from post edit page. You only need to select sticky option for that post you want to put forward, don't need to select sticky option on all posts.

Comment: Yes I now that, But If I have more than one post I want to put forward ? Then I would retrieve all the sticky post but also not sticky with an unique WP_query

Comment: You can make as many sticky posts as you want and they will all appear above regular posts. If you have selected sticky option for 3 posts then these 3 posts will appear first then your latest post will appear.

Comment: Ok but my case is a bit specific. My team created the theme we use, then we have a dropdown with all articles from a category. So here I made a WP_query, to get all the post from 'my_category', but I have some sticky_post now, so if I normally retrieve all these posts, Sticky or not there is no order changes..