# How to search for (partial match) display names of WordPress users?

Tags: search, users, wp-user-query

I need to create a search page that will display anything related to the supplied search.
i.e. `comments` containing it, `events`, `posts`, `CPT`s and `users` with that name.

How can I search for users in the site who's first or last name contains the search phrase ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Searching the main table

Simply use [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) with a search argument.

So if you want to search for example for a user with a keyword in his `user_email` or similar columns from the `{$wpdb->prefix}users` table, then you can do the following:

```
$users = new WP_User_Query( array(
    'search'         => '*'.esc_attr( $your_search_string ).'*',
    'search_columns' => array(
        'user_login',
        'user_nicename',
        'user_email',
        'user_url',
    ),
) );
$users_found = $users->get_results();
```

Keep in mind that `*` is a wildcard. So restricting for example the `user_email` to a single domain would give you the following search string: `*@example.com`.

The `search` string has some "magic" features: The `search_columns` defaults to...

- `user_email` if `@` is present in the `search` arg.
- `user_login` and `ID` if the `search` arg is numeric
- `user_url` if the `search` string contains `http://` or `https://`
- or ... `user_login` and `user_nicename` if a string is present.

All those defaults are only set if *no* `search_columns` argument was specified.

### Searching the meta table

If you want to search by for example `first_name` or `last_name`, then you'll have to do a `meta_query` as they're not part of the main table:

```
$search_string = esc_attr( trim( get_query_var('s') ) );
$users = new WP_User_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'first_name',
            'value'   => $search_string,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'last_name',
            'value'   => $search_string,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
) );
$users_found = $users->get_results();
```

Make sure you retrieve the right search string. Normally that would be `get_query_var('s');`, but it could - depending on your form `name/id` as well be something different that you might want to retrieve using `$_GET['user_search']` for example. Make sure to properly esacpe it and remove unwanted white space from the beginning and end of the string.

Keep in mind that this is an `array( array() )` as there's the `relation` key. If you just want to have a single key searched, it might be easier to just go with the following:

```
$search_string = esc_attr( trim( get_query_var('s') ) );
$users = new WP_User_Query( array(
    'meta_key'     => 'first_name',
    'meta_value'   => $search_string,
    'meta_compare' => 'LIKE',
) );
$users_found = $users->get_results();
```

### Final query

The result *might* look close to the following:

```
$search_string = esc_attr( trim( get_query_var('s') ) );
$users = new WP_User_Query( array(
    'search'         => "*{$search_string}*",
    'search_columns' => array(
        'user_login',
        'user_nicename',
        'user_email',
        'user_url',
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'first_name',
            'value'   => $search_string,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'last_name',
            'value'   => $search_string,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
) );
$users_found = $users->get_results();
```

Comment: In which file i want to add this query?

Comment: @Naveen Best fit would be either the `functions.php`, your template or (which would be best) wrapped up nicely in a custom mini-plugin to not loose functionality when switching themes.

Comment: Kiaser thanks for your reply. please help me how can i integrate this code to functions.php

Comment: @Naveen That's out of scope here. You'll have to learn a bit about code or find a developer to do that for you. And [read that Q/A](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/where-do-i-put-the-code-snippets-i-found-here-or-somewhere-else-on-the-web).

Comment: `display_name` is a column in `wp_users`. Two questions come to mind. 1: Is this a recent change to the database schema? 2: Can it be used as a value in `search_columns` instead of the meta query?

Comment: @kaiser instead of `user_email` `email` works , as in core file /var/www/html/rated_lettings/wp-includes/class-wp-user-query.php  #163 $search_columns      Array of column names to be searched. Accepts 'ID', 'login','nicename', 'email', 'url'. Default empty array.

<br/>
am i missing some thing

Comment: @inrsaurabh it's been 5 years since that answer. No idea if and what changed there. :)

Comment: @kaiser i think than i am correct we should use `email`

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-user-query.php#L162

Comment: @inrsaurabh Take [a look here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d668b72f5b96cfeb477e150106345b21dfd9add7/wp-includes/class-wp-user-query.php#L517-L547).

Answer (score 0):

This helped me instead of kaiser's answer: https://laubsterboy.com/blog/2015/07/search-wordpress-users-by-name/

But in this solution `$wpdb->escape($usermeta_keys)` function generated an error, so I simply used `$usermeta_keys`.

Answer (score 0):

## Custom solution

I know my answer is late, but i was looking for the same thing and build it with some help of @kaiser his answer. I'm only going to display the title, link and excerpt/user email, but you can expand this in the way you want offcourse.

### Custom array

I started by creating an empty array:

```
$search_results = array();
```

### User search

Then moved on with the 'WP_User_Query' which uses the user-input ($search_results) for filtering.

```
$search_string = esc_attr( trim( get_query_var('s') ) );
$users = new WP_User_Query( array(
    'search'         => "*{$search_string}*",
    'search_columns' => array(
        'user_login',
        'user_nicename',
        'user_email',
        'user_url',
    ),
) );
```

### Fill our array with user data

Now we gonna fill this query in our empty ($search_results) array.

```
if (!empty($users->results)) :
    foreach ($users->results as $user => $value) :
        $tmp_array = array();
        $data = $value->data;
        $user_id = $data->ID;
        $tmp_array['link'] = get_the_author_link($user_id); 
        $tmp_array['text'] = $data->user_url;
        $tmp_array['title'] = $data->display_name;
        $search_results[] = $tmp_array;
    endforeach;
endif;
```

### Fill our array with post/page data

We also want the 'normal' search form that searches for pages and post to still work, so we need to loop over this as well. While we do this, we are also gonna fill our ($search_results) array with this data:

```
$query_string = esc_attr($query_string);
$search = new WP_Query($query_string);
if ( $search->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $search->have_posts() ) : $search->the_post();
        $tmp_array = array();
        $tmp_array['link'] = get_the_permalink();; 
        $tmp_array['title'] = get_the_title();
        $tmp_array['text'] = get_the_excerpt();
        $search_results[] = $tmp_array;
    endwhile;
endif;
```

### Loop over our array

Now we have an array that contains user info and post/page details.
The last thing we need to do now is looping over it, so the user sees the results he searched for:

```
<?php if(!empty($search_results)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($search_results as $result) : ?>
        <a class="search-item" href="<?php echo $result['link']; ?>">
            <h2 class="search-title"><?php echo $result['title']; ?></h2>
            <span class="search-text"><?php echo $result['text']; ?></span>
        </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="nothing-found">
    <h3><?php echo 'No results found.'; ?></h3>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

### Done!

Comment: I guess that might be a good idea for a small user collection...

Answer (score 0):

Recently when I was working on a large scale project, my clients were facing problems while searching users with their first name, last name, business name/company name.

So I thought, lets create a plugin and combine my front-end skills with Php. I decided to go with VueJs and Axios to accomplish my mission.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/robust-user-search/

This plugin allow users to search by : **Username, First name, Last name, Email or Business Name**.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Please note that you should disclose your affiliation when promoting stuff, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/promotion

Comment: @AnttiKoskinen Hey is this better now?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using simpler get_user() function, you can use the following code:

```
$users = get_users(array('search' => '*'.esc_attr( $search_string).'*'));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$search_string = esc_attr( trim( get_query_var('s') ) );
$users = new WP_User_Query( array(
    'search'         => "*{$search_string}*",
    'search_columns' => array(
        'user_login',
        'user_nicename',
        'user_email',
        'user_url',
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'first_name',
            'value'   => $search_string,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'last_name',
            'value'   => $search_string,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
) );
$users_found = $users->get_results();
```