# Is it necessary to escape LIKE term in WP_User_Query?

Tags: wp-user-query, escaping, wpdb

While searching for partial string searches using [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) I came across this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/105173) by @kaiser who has provided some great answers here on Stackexchange. However, I was confused over the use of `esc_attr` to escape the LIKE term (`'search' => '*' . esc_attr( $your_search_string ) . '*'`).

I believe `WP_User_Query` makes use of prepared statements where such escaping would be unnecessary and a futile exercise. Am I right?

Secondly, if at all, escaping has to be done, wouldn't [`like_escape()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/like_escape) suit the purpose better?

Answer (score 1):

[`like_escape()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/like_escape) only escapes `%` and `_` characters.  The entire function looks like this:

```
function like_escape($text) {
   return str_replace(array("%", "_"), array("\\%", "\\_"), $text);
}
```

Quoting from the Codex, [`esc_attr()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr)

> Encodes the <, >, &, " and ' (less than, greater than, ampersand, double quote and single quote) characters. Will never double encode entities.
>
> **Always use when escaping HTML attributes** (especially form values) such as alt, value, title, etc.

(Emphasis mine.)

Further reading:  [Data Validation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation)

**Edited to add** -- I didn't address the first part of the question:  If [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) does its own data validation, then do we really need to use `esc_attr()` at all?

The Codex page for `WP_User_Query` doesn't seem to say one way or the other whether any data validation is done.  (Searching the page for `valid` and `escape` turns up nothing, as well.)  This, combined with a note from the `esc_attr()` page -- "*Will never double encode entities*" -- indicates to me that there's no harm in using `esc_attr()` on the values you're passing.  Better safe than sorry, especially with untrusted user-provided data, right?