# Allow users to search for other users in Wordpress

Tags: search

I have a plugin that I've created within my site, which just shows one page where I'm calling all users and then some specific information about those users.

Would it be possible to allow users to search for other existing users from the front end of the site?

This is the kind of thing I've got going on at the moment, I haven;t been able to find any kind of search of this sort of thing, so if anyone could point me in the right direction it's be very much appreciated,

I haven;t included any code as it's not that relevant really, but I can include it if needs be,

Thanks in advance!

http://focusedlearning.hcrlaw.com/courses-admin/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add Search member/user feature in your plugin then you can follow below guide link.

[How can I search for a worpress user by display name or a part of it?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105168/how-can-i-search-for-a-worpress-user-by-display-name-or-a-part-of-it)

AND

If you want to go with any plugin then you can use below link plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/amr-users/

Demo: http://directories.wpusersplugin.com/simple-user-list/

Comment: Thanks you for this, do you know if the plug in will allow me to display custom code for each user?

Comment: What exactly are you referring to a "custom code"? Do you want to customize the plugin? If yes, then I'm not sure because not customized it.

Comment: Well at the moment, I'm pulling in information from events each user has attended (see the link in my question) so I'm not sure a plugin is the best answer but I'll definitely have a look. Thank you for your time anyway!