# How to insert custom function into wp_insert_post

Tags: wp-insert-post

i'm trying to send push notification when the wordpress admin insert new post.

I was looking for hours where to add my function and after a lot i found core function `wp_insert_post` inside `wp-includes/post.php`

that function returns the Post_ID, so i added my custom script before return:

```
include '../push/send_message.php';
sendNotification($postarr['post_title'],$postarr['guid']);
```

The problem is that when i import these two rows here

```
function wp_insert_post($postarr, $wp_error = false) {
    ...
    if ( $update ) {
        do_action('edit_post', $post_ID, $post);
        $post_after = get_post($post_ID);
        do_action( 'post_updated', $post_ID, $post_after, $post_before);
    }
    do_action('save_post', $post_ID, $post);
    do_action('wp_insert_post', $post_ID, $post);
    include '../push/send_message.php';
    sendNotification($postarr['post_title'],$postarr['guid']);
    return $post_ID;
}
```

nothing happen and when admin insert new post, the success page is blank. if i remove that line all is ok.. very strange.. Can someone give me a right way to do what i need?

Comment: What do you mean by "added my custom script before return"? Are you hacking the Core file?

Comment: if you see my answer, you can see that before return $post_ID i've added my two custom rows. I never worked with wordpress and i don't know how to do what i need and this is for me the smart solution.

Comment: That is a core function, you should never alter the core files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See those two hooks in the hacked Core code you posted?

```
do_action('save_post', $post_ID, $post);
do_action('wp_insert_post', $post_ID, $post);
```

Those are what you need to use to do this right.

```
function run_on_update_post($post_ID, $post) {
    var_dump($post_ID, $post); // debug
    include '../push/send_message.php';
    sendNotification($post['post_title'],$post['guid']);
    return $post_ID;

}
add_action('save_post', 'run_on_update_post', 1, 2);
```

`save_post` runs every time the post is saved. I can't swear that your function will work but you should be able to modify things to make it work. Just look at the `var_dump` and alter accordingly. The `include`s may not work either, as they are relative paths. You may have to change that as well.

Comment: Where i need to add add_action?

Comment: Putting that in a plugin would be best but it will work from the theme's `functions.php`.

Comment: ok, i add your code inside a plugin that i've activate. Inside callback function,i put a simple print_r($_POST);. The problem is that i see that only when i click on "create new article" and not when i publish it. How can i edit to achive what i need?

Comment: Put `die;` after your `print_r($_POST);`. Do you see it now?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying core files is a *no-go*. The [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) provides the connection you need for doing this kind of things. The function you're modifying has plenty of [hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks) available. Also see: [Actions and filters are NOT the same thing…](http://ottopress.com/2011/actions-and-filters-are-not-the-same-thing/).

The solution is to create your own plugin <sup>`*`</sup>:

```
<?php
/* Plugin name: My first plugin */

add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'callback_so_17530930', 10, 2 );

function callback_so_17530930( $post_ID, $post )
{
    // Adjust for the desired Post Type
    if( 'page' !== $post->post_type )
        return;

    include '../push/send_message.php';
    sendNotification( $post->post_title, $post->guid );
}
```

<sup>`*`</sup> See [Where do I put the code snippets I found here or somewhere else on the web?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/72160/12615)

Just drop the plugin PHP file inside `wp-content/plugins` folder. Go to the dashboard plugins' page and activate. More details at [the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

Comment: ok, i add plugin and i've activated it. I put in your code, inside callback function, a simple print_r($_POST);. The problem is that i see that only when i click on "create new article" and not when i publish it. How can i edit to achive what i need?

Comment: Use the `save_post` action hook. Check [this Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2bsave_post%20%2bdoing_autosave%20%2bpost_type%20is%3aanswer) for working examples.

Comment: if you see the answer above yours, @s_ha_dum says me to use save_post. Using it the result is the same as yours

Comment: I think the problem you posted is covered in both answers: use hooks for it to work. Now you're working with a different code. As I said, research within the working examples. To [debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) this specific hooks you need to `die()` after `print_r()/var_dump()`, or use FirePHP or similar.