# Is there a way to fire other functions from wp_insert_post

Tags: wp-insert-post, plugin-jetpack

I am creating a new post using the `wp_insert_post` function. Here's what that code looks like:

```
$new_post = array(
            'post_title' => $newtitle,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_content' => $repost[content],
            'post_excerpt' => $repost[excerpt],
            'post_author' => 1,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_category' => explode(",",$catlist),
         );

        wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

The post is created fine, but I'd like to fire some other functions, such as Jetpack's social posting tools (Publicize.) Is there code to do that or would I be better in changing the post_status to draft and setting a future publishing date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code snippet to use another function,

```
function my_function( $post_id ) {

    //Some code
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_function' );
```

This fires when a post is inserted.

Comment: Keep in mind this also fires when a post is updated.

Comment: Yes @hereswhatidid.. This fires along with the existing functionality.

Comment: Thanks - you can also hook into wp_insert_post I learned from this answer in another thread [Post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/105745/50634)

Comment: Yeah Great. If your problem is fixed, please update your answer and mark the question as resolved. So others will get help from this post :)

Answer (score 1):

`wp_insert_post` will [trigger a number of hooks](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3225):

- `save_post_{$post->post_type}`
- `save_post`
- `wp_insert_post`
- [the transition post hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_transition_post_status)
- possibly `edit_post` and `post_updated`
- and certainly some others

So, yes, there are a number of ways to trigger other functions. Use [`add_action`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) or [`add_filter`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) to apply a callback to the hook appropriate for your purpose.