# add a function to submit options.php

Tags: functions

I have a form which does

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">
.........
<input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e( 'Save changes', 'bsp_style_settings' ); ?>" />
```

I have all the register settings/admin_init's etc. and it all works fine and saves the data to WP_Options part of the database- great !

All I want to do is add an additional function that is also carried out on submit. So simple call to say

```
function also_do () {
xxxx
}
```

so this function also executes when save is pressed.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Probably something like this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141937/is-there-a-way-to-fire-other-functions-from-wp-insert-post

Comment: What does the function do?

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a check for settings updated, and call a function.

At the top of the page that renders the settings form:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['settings-updated'] ) && $_GET['settings_updated'] == true ) {
    your_custom_function();
}
```

Then define the custom function in your functions.php or add it to a class.

Comment: The `settings-updated` query is added *after* the form has submitted, in a new request. The process: form is submitted, server handles the data, browser is redirected to `?settings-updated=1`. This is so that pressing F5 doesn't submit the information again, which might cause problems. This method should be avoided or, at the very least, used carefully. Also mind that if 'settings-updated' is set, the form data you submitted will NOT be present (as I said, it's a new request following a redirect).

Comment: Yes, but for the purposes of the question, it is a quick-and-dirty way to fire off a custom function. The data is available through the options as opposed to the $_REQUEST, which is ideal as it has already been sanitized and can be safely passed to other functions (assuming it was sanitized properly).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `updated_option` hook.

[From the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/updated_option/):

> `do_action( 'updated_option', string $option, mixed $old_value, mixed $value )`
>
> Fires after the value of an option has been successfully updated.

There is also the `update_option` hook which fires before an option is updated.