# Is it possible to put tags and category information in the post as text?

Tags: categories, tags

Is it possible to put tags and category information in the post area, so one doesn't have to click the appropriate fields and use the mouse? Ideally I just want to type "#art" "cat:painting" in the text editor and word press automatically assigns these values to the post once I hit "Post".

Comment: One possibility would be to hook into WP at the moment a post gets created. There you may extract the tags from your post_content and save them into the post_category. Have a look at wp_post_insert and save_post. Maybe [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/105731) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin for using hashtags in the post - [hashtagger](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hashtagger/). It will override the normal way you'd add tags which has caused confusion for some of my users but it works.

You can also look at the process around [creating tags/posts via shortcode](https://en.support.wordpress.com/post-by-email/#shortcodes) through the Jetpack post via email option.