# Publish Post After Click On A Link

Tags: plugins, posts, plugin-development, permalinks, publish

I have a frontend posting form (CF7), where user inputs (among other data of course) his email. Now I set the status to pending.

What I want is, that the user would get trough autoresponder a mail, in which would be the link for changing the status to PUBLISH when clicked on. Is there any solution for this? Autoresponder is not the problem, I do not know, how to set up this link.

Answer (score 1):

When the post is created and set to `pending`, build a unique identifier for auto-publishing, for example:

```
$unique = md5( $post->post_content );
add_post_meta( $post->ID, '_auto_publish', $unique );
```

Now create a link for the email:

```
$link = get_permalink( $post->ID );
$link = add_query_arg(
    array(
        'autopublish' => $unique,
        'pid'         => $post->ID
    ),
    $link
);
```

Send this link in your email to the submitter’s address:

```
print "<$link>";
```

Then watch for the matching `$_GET` parameters when the recipient clicks the link:

```
if ( isset ( $_GET[ 'autopublish' ] )
    and isset ( $_GET[ 'pid' ] )
    and is_numeric( $_GET[ 'pid' ] )
    and $post = get_post( $_GET[ 'pid' ] )
    and $_GET[ 'autopublish' ] === get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_auto_publish', TRUE )
    )
{
    $post->post_status = 'publish';
    wp_update_post( $post );
    delete_post_meta( $post->ID, '_auto_publish' );
}
```

Comment: Is this working also for unregistered users?

Comment: There is currently no check for registration, so yes, it should work. I haven’t tested this code, it is just an idea.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please point me where to include this, im quite poor in php. How much you would charge for this to implement (if you have time)?

Comment: I would create this as a plugin, see [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/where-do-i-put-the-code-snippets-i-found-here-or-somewhere-else-on-the-web). It depends on your form set up where the first part has to to be set. And no, I don’t have much time currently.

Comment: Ok thanks! In the newsletter I suppose I should then include <a href="<?php echo $link ?>activate</a>, right?

Comment: Yes. I would send a plain text email and enclose the URL with `<` and `>` like `<http://example.com>` for maximum compatibility.

Comment: hm, dont understand this.. The mail will be sent in auto response. How would even that code/plugin know, to which user he needs to send the link. The link will of course be sent immediately after the form would be sent. And as far the link is concirned, you mean that it should look like this: <http://example.com/<?php echo $link ?>>.. im lost :(

Comment: ok, it will know through the autoresponder.. sorry for that, clear now. And in autoresponder I need to include this link. I made a plugin now, but stuck again..

Comment: See my update; I have added a little code example.

Comment: really appreciate it! thanks. And the other code (except the print.. ) is in the same file (plugin)? Will try now!

Comment: Now the problem is, that i cannot include php to contact form 7 autoresponder. Damn, it looked so good. Is there any solution for that?