# Is it possible to add custom business logic to a Custom Post Admin Edit Page?

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type that has a few fields that accept amounts. Each amount is editable. I would like to display the total of these amounts in another non-editable field on the same Custom Post Admin Page.

Is this possible?

Comment: This sounds jQuery, no?

Comment: Its not the jQuery that bothers me, but where fo I write the Javascript for it all to show up on the Edit Custom Post Type Page?

Comment: You can easily create meta box and pull in some content to display like the total value of a bunch of other custom fields. But if they edit the other fields it won't update the total until the post is saved.

Comment: Maybe it isnt possible because I have used plugins to create the custom post types and there isnt an option to add Javascript anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/72160/12615) to add JavaScript (and stylesheets) in targeted admin pages. By the description, I think the better is to inject the *total amount* field together with the existent fields. Or you can create a meta box to display it. And use Stack Overflow for all your jQuery needs.

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: My plugin */

# Run only in /wp-admin/post.php
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post.php', function()
{
    global $typenow;

    // Run only for the types Posts and Movies
    if( !in_array( $typenow, array( 'post', 'movie' ) ) )
        return;

    # codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script
    wp_enqueue_script( 
            'my-custom-posts', 
            plugins_url( '/my-custom-posts.js', __FILE__ ), 
            array(), // dependencies
            false, // version
            true // on footer
    );
    # codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script
    wp_localize_script( 
        'my-custom-posts', 
        'my_vars',
        array( 'typenow' => $typenow ) 
    );
});
```

And the file `my-custom-posts.js` in the same folder as your plugin:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
{    
    alert( my_vars.typenow );
    // do your stuff
});
```