# How to edit link for comment count

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, disqus

I have recently installed Disqus on my blog and have a problem with the link in the comment count.

On the main page [here](https://scotthelme.co.uk) all the comments counts for each post link to the appropriate URL for the post with `#disqus_thread` appended to take the user to the comment section at the bottom.

If you navigate to the post by clicking the title like [here](https://scotthelme.co.uk/vpn-security-privacy-online/) the link on the comment count changes to `#respond` which doesn't work.

How/where do I edit this value to be `#disqus_thread` so it takes the user to the comments below as it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the section of code I needed to modify in `wp-includes\comment-template.php`:

I changed this:

```
return apply_filters( 'get_comments_link', get_permalink( $post_id ) . '#comments', $post_id );
```

To this:

```
return apply_filters( 'get_comments_link', get_permalink( $post_id ) . '#disqus_thread', $post_id );
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter `get_comments_link` to change the URL. You get two arguments: the link and the post ID.

```
add_filter( 'get_comments_link', function( $link, $post_id ) 
{
    return get_permalink( $post_id ) . '#disqus_thread';
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Please excuse my lack of experience in WP but where do I need to add the filter?

Comment: @ScottHelme In a plugin or your theme’s `functions.php`. See [Where do I put the code snippets?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72183/73)

Comment: I get a fatal exception when creating my own plugin, it will not activate.

Comment: @ScottHelme Sorry, had a typo in my code. :) Fixed now.

Comment: Still no joy: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in *snip*/fixcommentlink.php on line 10` with line 10 being `add_filter( 'get_comments_link', function( $link, $post_id ) `

Comment: @ScottHelme Your PHP version is very outdated. Upgrade to 5.5 or at least 5.4. Your version 5.2 is insecure, slow, and missing features.