# htaccess breaks periodically

Tags: htaccess

Ever since a few weeks, my .htaccess gets consistenly broken every few days. Sometimes it just gets an extraneous character at the end of file, but most of the times it's part of the file duplicated, like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBa
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

My best guess is that some plugin is rewriting the htaccess and it's obviously not doing it properly. These are the plugins I have installed:

- Akismet
- All In One SEO Pack
- CopyRightPro
- DB Cache Reloaded
- Hello Dolly
- Jetpack por WordPress.com
- MediaElement.js - HTML5 Audio and Video
- Ninja Forms
- qTranslate
- Rapid Twitter Widget
- Recent Facebook Posts
- Simple Backup
- Spider Facebook.
- Twitget
- Under Construction
- WP Super Cache
- WP Twitter widget by rYokiNG

Any ideas?

Comment: See [WordPress keeps writing rewrite rules to .htaccess](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/118731/wordpress-keeps-writing-rewrite-rules-to-htaccess).

Comment: Where should I put the line they mention? I tried in functions.php but it causes my website to crash

Comment: Try a [separate plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72183/73).

Comment: thanks! can't I vote your comments?