# Where to put code to get custom taxonomy term id?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, functions

Let me preface this by saying that I am new to Wordpress customization and don't know how to write code, but I can stumble through customizations involving simple copy/paste instructions. So, this question is *very* basic. Sorry.

I'm using a plugin that asks for the term id for the custom taxonomy that I've created.  I have found some posts that explain how to do this and give little php snippets (e.g. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-echo-custom-taxonomy-id).  But I really have no idea where to put this code. Could you please help?

UPDATE: I do know how to create php files via copy/paste and upload to my server, basic stuff like that...

Comment: What plugin asks for it? What are you trying to accomplish? Is that the plugin settings asking for this info or is it for a plugin function in the theme?

Comment: I'm using A-Z Glossary.  I'm trying to create a keyword index where each term has just one entry. But the only set-up of A-Z glossary that I can figure out lists the terms, then when you click on one takes you to a page that, in theory, groups all of the posts/pages by the taxonomy term, then you click on the entry and get to the page. I want to bypass that step where the page lists all of the pages/posts with the term because the term will only be connected to a single page. The developer says that it's possible by listing the term id in a field in the plugin settings.

Comment: [Where do I put the code snippets?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72183/73)

Comment: Thank you! I was able to find the term ids, but the plugin is still not doing what I want it to :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your WP database there a table named wp_terms. There you can see all terms ids (term_id) and all terms names (term_name). That should give you what you need. If you don't have access to your WP database you can you a plugin to do that. I use one called Adminer, but there are others that do that. Once you install Adminer you can acccess your database from Tools->Adminer - Start Adminer.

Another way to do that is to use the function "get_terms". But that involves editing one of your wordpress templates (php files).
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms