# CPT to installable Plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I have gotten pretty good at creating CPT's for clients sites, but now would like to take it a step further by making them plugins outside of the theme so when/if they decide to change themes it is one less thing I need to think about. Or maybe it is a really well thought out CPT and want to offer it to others to install on their site through the plugin repo.

I was wondering how to do this? I know I need to create the views, but not sure how to register them and make it all come together.

Answer (score 1):

There are other factors that you'll discover along the way, but basically it boils down to: move all that's CPT related from your theme's `functions.php` to a plugin file.

Create a PHP file, put the [plugin's header information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin), add to the plugins folder, activate. 
Now, you separated appearance (theme) from functionality (plugin). Here are two fundamental Q&A's here in WPSE:

- [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031)
- [Where do I put the code snippets I found here or somewhere else on the web?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/72160)

And here a [related blog post](http://www.doitwithwp.com/create-functions-plugin/).

You'll find many examples of [plugin-development](/questions/tagged/plugin-development) in the site archives.

Comment: Thank you so much! Great job laying out the resources available!

Comment: I was librarian when young ;)