# Advanced Custom Fields and Yoast SEO keyword analysis

Tags: filters, actions, advanced-custom-fields, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

The problem I'm having is the **keyword page analysis tool** doesn't read my custom fields so I am trying to figure out how to run a filter on them.

I found a blog post on Yoast website here [here](http://yoast.com/wordpress-seo-content-analysis/) which references this issue and they list the filter `wpseo_pre_analysis_post_content`, but I am unsure of how to run this on the fields.

I found an action for running a function on the admin edit screen on the [ACF website : acf/input/admin_head](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/actions/acfinputadmin_head/), but I don't know how to run the filter on the actions that have been loaded.

EDIT:

I found out the acf plugin actually has this filter built in but doesnt seem to be working.

```
        // set value
        if( !isset($field['value']) )
        {
            $field['value'] = apply_filters('acf/load_value', false, $post_id, $field);
            $field['value'] = apply_filters('acf/format_value', $field['value'], $post_id, $field);

            apply_filters( 'wpseo_pre_analysis_post_content', $field['value'] );
        }
```

Comment: Simply ignore Yoast and his recommendations. No one is going to implement a filter callback into his plugin just to let Joosts plugin do obscure stuff.

Comment: @kaiser, priceless ^^^^^^ just added to a [newly started collection](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qW7lW.png) . . I think I'm gonna flag it `Not a comment, should be a twitter or converted in an answer`

Comment: @brasofilo Is that list publicly available somewhere?

Comment: You are missing `10, 2` when adding the filter (compare your code to mine). Ten is the priority given to the filter (1 higher, 99 lower). And 2 is the number of arguments `($content,$post)` that the callback receives.

Comment: I noticed another post on the support thread. When you add a string to the the content it still wont recognize it. I can confirm this doesnt work. See edit.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the filter:

```
$post_content = apply_filters( 'wpseo_pre_analysis_post_content', $post->post_content, $post );
```

it would be a matter of adding your fields content to string being analyzed.

You have to do the `get_field()` part right, this is untested:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_pre_analysis_post_content', 'filter_yoasts_wpse_119879', 10, 2 );

function filter_yoasts_wpse_119879( $content, $post )
{
    $fields = get_field( 'name', $post->ID );
    return $content . $fields;
}
```

As noted by kaiser in comments, the `get_field()` function is not reliable. If it is a relatively simple field, it's better to stick to [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta).

<sub>*Related: [Where do I put the code snippets I found here or somewhere else on the web?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/72160/12615)*</sub>

Comment: +1 But from what I had to deal with the ACF plugin so far, I'm not sure if that will really work out. It got some pretty nasty and shady "behind the scenes"-retrieval of the md5 hashed meta field name. So there're actually two fields: One with the value, the other one with the name. And the name for the field holding the actual value gets dynamically generated somewhere in callback hell. Could never really get a repeatable result on when and where that happened.

Comment: Oh, sure, sure, many times I've ended up using `get_post_meta` and decoding ACF stuff myself. I'll add a note to the A.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I found a solution on the Wordpress support page but when I try to run this function I get a missing argument error. See my update please.

Answer (score 2):

Ho, @hyperdrive - we wrestled with the exact same scenario and need and wrapped our solution / approach in a plugin:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/ns-seo-custom-fields/

You can use the standard custom field name(s) from the edit interface or ACF's "Field Name" value, and there's a screenshot to show where to find those exact values:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/ns-seo-custom-fields/screenshots/

We just released it and it works for us so let us know if it works well for you too. You can probably scavenge what you need from the plugin itself, or modify it to fit your exact needs... or check out the pro version that does even more including unlimited field support.