# Wordpress wp_loaded action hook

Tags: hooks, actions

I am using Shortcode exec php plugin and putting PHP code in a post via Wordpress Posts panel.

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'echoFunction');

function echoFunction(){
    echo "someText";
}
```

Why doesn't this work? and how do I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wp_loaded` is called long, long before the post content is fetched. [Put that code into a plugin.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72183/73)

Also, you shouldn't `echo` anything that early. The HTTP headers aren't sent yet on `wp_loaded`, so you will get the *Headers already sent* error, and your user authentication will not work: you cannot log in anymore.

Comment: You mean I should make my own plugin, yes? Ty

Comment: @user2879175 Yes, exactly. :) I have added a link to my answer that leads to a post explaining how to do that.