# Writing PHP code in pages without issue?

Tags: php

I've currently been using a plugin called Insert PHP that's just laughably bad and the cause of a lot of headaches. I have a lot of PHP code running in different Pages on my installation, so I was wondering if there's a way to **include** the .php files and write in a normal text editor?

Comment: I like to create shortcodes. In my shortcode callbacl function I write all my php, then I insert the shortcode into my post/page

Answer (score 2):

Writing code in a WP post is not a good idea. As [czerspalace mentions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204325/writing-php-code-in-pages-without-issue#comment296427_204325) the easiest solution is to use a [Custom Field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) to paste the code and use a [Shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to render it in HTML.

**The post would be like:**

[image]

<sup>Any number of shortcodes can be used, just put a unique name for each *field name*,

in this example `cod-1` (an arbitrary name).</sup>

**The Custom Field:**

[image]

**Plugin code:**
<sub>See [Where do I put the code snippets I found here or somewhere else on the web?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/where-do-i-put-the-code-snippets-i-found-here-or-somewhere-else-on-the-web/72183#72183)</sub>

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SOpt) Shortcode para código HTML
 * Plugin URI: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/86941/201
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: brasofilo 
 */

add_shortcode( 'codigo', 'shortcode_sopt_83496' );

function shortcode_sopt_83496( $atts )
{
    global $post;

    // field not defined, do nothing
    if ( !isset( $atts['field'] ) )
        return '';

    // get custom field attribute value from Shortcode's "field"
    $code = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $atts['field'], true );

    // envelops code in <pre> tag, stilize at will with CSS
    return sprintf(
        '<pre class="codigo-front">%s</pre>', 
        htmlentities( $code, ENT_QUOTES )
    );
}
```

**Result:**

> [image]

<sub>*Any Custom Fields plugin can be used to make a nice interface, instead of WP default.*</sub>

<sup><sub>[Originally posted](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/86941/201) at Stack Overflow em Português</sub></sup>